# Changing RectangleGeometry.Rect on window resize in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a `RectangleGeometry` for clipping a certain area of a window. However, when the window is resized I'd like the `RectangleGeometry.Rect` property to be adjusted such that the clipping position doesn't change as the window resizes. Is there an event I'd have to lookout for to dynamically change the property? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to handle the SizeChanged event on your Window, then adjust your clipping rectangle accordingly.